# Java Grect And Private Static ERROR

Tags: java, static, private, rect

This is code:

```
    package main;

import java.awt.*;
import acm.graphics.*;
import acm.program.*;

public class AjorBandi extends GraphicsProgram{

public void run(){
    private static final BRICK_TOOL=30 ;
    private static final BRICK_ARZ = 10;
    int x,y;
    x=0;
    y=100;
    for(int ii=0;ii<14;ii++){
    for(int i= 0;i<14;i++){
        Grect rect = new Grect(x,y,BRICK_TOOL,BRICK_ARZ);
        add(rect);
        x+=30;
        i-=1;       


    }
    y+=10;
    x+=15;


    }

}
```

}

This is Grect error messages from eclipse:

```
    Multiple markers at this line
- Grect cannot be resolved to a 
 type
- Grect cannot be resolved to a 
 type
```

This is     `private static`     error messages:

```
    Multiple markers at this line
- Line breakpoint:AjorBandi [line: 10] - run()
- Syntax error on token "final", float expected
- Illegal modifier for parameter BRICK_TOOL; only final is 
 permitted
```

I have compile error with this i eclipse IDE.
What is the problem of this 2 errors?

Comment: Java is case sensitive. It's [GRect](http://cs.stanford.edu/people/eroberts/jtf/javadoc/student/acm/graphics/GRect.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your two variables

```
private static final BRICK_TOOL=30 ;
private static final BRICK_ARZ = 10;
```

have two problems.

They should be declared at **class level** and you are missing the *most important* thing, the **type**.
I give an example, where I use `int` for them:

```
public class MyClass
{
    private static final int BRICK_TOOL = 30;
    private static final int BRICK_ARZ = 10;

    myMethod()
    {
        //do stuff here
    {
}
```

Comment: Syntax error on token "final", float expected   when I put it in class and out of method

Comment: That is because you still haven't set a _type_ for the variable. Java is a [type-safe](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_safety#Java) language.

Comment: Consider replying and accepting the answer, if it helped you.